Why i cant invalidate multiple async provider?
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Future<HomePageData> homeData(HomeDataRef ref) async {
  final data = await Future.wait([
    ref.watch(walletBalanceProvider.future),
    ref.watch(marketTokensProvider.future),
    ref.watch(tokenChangesProvider.future),
    ref.watch(otcPairProvider.future),
  ]);

  return HomePageData(
    wallets: data[0] as List<Wallet>,
    marketTokens: data[1] as List<Token>,
    otcToken: data[2] as List<Token>,
    otcPair: data[3] as List<OtcPair>,
  );
}

i have homeDataProvider like this,
why when i call ref.invalidate(homeDataProvider) it will return error, but invalidating it one by one working.

You should be using final (v1, v2, v3, v4) = await (f1, f2, f3, f4).wait; to preserve the proper types.

Because it is keepAlive = true. perhaps the other ones are not singleton.
